# node express module throwing 'has no method urlencoded' error

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express=require('express')
var app=express();

console.log("Encoded ",express.urlencoded());

app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

The above code throws the following error :

```
[user@localhost nodejs]$ node program.js

/home/user/Desktop/nodejs/program.js:41
console.log("Encoded ",express.urlencoded());
                               ^
TypeError: Object function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, proto);
  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype);

  app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
  app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
  app.init();
  return app;
} has no method 'urlencoded'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Desktop/nodejs/program.js:41:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Seems like a similar question here - [express.js trouble with connect modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660879/express-js-trouble-with-connect-modules) but I'm already having express3.0.0 checked using the suggestion listed here - [Find the version of an installed npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package)

I also read the Api docs here - http://expressjs.com/api.html and they list `urlencoded()`

Please help.

I would also like to point, that I also tried using `bodyParser()` but that too gave the same error of `has no method`

Comment: Coding_idiot provides a solution. Or you can still use Express 3.4.8: `npm install express@3.4.8`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The express guide is a bit-outdated.

For others having the same problem, the solution is that those methods have moved to a new module `body-parser`

Sample Code

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

Comment: Thank you. My production server updated to a newer version and I was REALLY scratching my head on this one.